# Shouldn't char* implicitly converted to std::string?

Tags: c++

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct ST {};

bool operator==(const struct ST *s1, const string &s2) {
    return true;
}

int main() {
    struct ST *st = new ST();
    const char *p = "abc";

    if (st == p) {
        return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

I get compile error:

```
prog.cpp:14:12: error: comparison between distinct pointer types ‘ST*’ and ‘const char*’ lacks a cast [-fpermissive]
  if (st == p) {
            ^
```

I wonder why the implicit conversion from char* to string does not work here?

UPDATE
Anton's answer makes sense, I updated the code:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct ST {};

bool operator==(const struct ST s1, const string &s2) {
    return true;
}

int main() {
    struct ST st;
    const char *p = "abc";

    if (st == p) {
        return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Now it compiles.

Comment: You compare different type of pointers here. Your overloaded operator isn't evoked.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but `#include <iostream>` is not required here. `#include <string>` is.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[§13.3.1.2 Operators in expressions [over.match.oper]](http://www.lcdf.org/c%2B%2B/clause13.html#s13.3.1.2) states:

> If no operand of an operator in an expression has a type that is a class or an enumeration, the operator is assumed to be a built-in operator and interpreted according to Clause 5.

This is exactly your case: `operator==`'s arguments are pointers, so it's considered to be built-in and compiler doesn't look for possible overloads.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely not.

First of all, you are trying to use a pointer in place of a reference.  Any similarity between a pointer and a reference is a implementation detail.  Remember the motto:  "Implementation Is Irrelevant!"

Next, and more directly to your question, a std::string and a char* are quite different, even if they are used to represent the same things.  Conversion between them was deliberately made difficult to prevent using them interchangably.

Comment: I think you've missed that although `st == p` is rejected, `operator==(st, p)` is perfectly valid and has the exact behaviour the OP is hoping to get with `st == p`. A `const string &` can be initialised from a temporary of type `string`, and a temporary of type `string` can be constructed from `const char *`.